# Can you override a DNS entry that you've delegated to another name server?

Tags: dns

Let's say I have two DNS servers

DNS Server 1 (dnsserver1.com)
test.mydomain.com NS dnsserver2.com
hello.test.mydomain.com CNAME [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com)

DNS Server 2 (dnsserver2.com)
hello.test.mydomain.com CNAME [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

According to my tests, if you visit hello.test.mydomain.com it'll display google.com, but I'm wondering if there's a way to override the delegation. Reason for this being that I'm switching my second DNS server (dnsserver2.com -> dnsserver3.com) and I would like to test this new delegation by individually overriding entries before I swap over the entire delegation.

Comment: If you delegate (`NS` records) something, then you can not have in your zone any record below that name. The DNS does not work the way you think it does. And you do not need to do all of that just to test a change in nameservers: any good DNS diagnostic tool, like DNSviz or Zonemaster online, allows to test  "undelegated" domains, that is a given configuration on a set of nameservers not yet appearing in parent zone. Hence you can conduct all needed tests before switching.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/358629/can-i-delegate-part-of-a-zone-to-another-server), specifically:

> Also note that any local zones you create would step on and override any outside DNS server's zones: It's not possible to have the A record for pc.home.mydomain.tld come from one NS and the AAAA record for it come from another: DNS delegates and declares authority by zone name, and that authority is for all record types within that zone.
> If a nameserver is told it is authoritative for something and can't find the record it will not forward the query up the DNS tree, it will simply return NXDOMAIN.

As a result, my plan is to delegate individual records a second time like so:

DNS Server 1 (dnsserver1.com)
test.mydomain.com NS dnsserver2.com

DNS Server 2 (dnsserver2.com)
hello.test.mydomain.com NS dnsserver3.com

DNS Server 3 (dnsserver3.com)
hello.test.mydomain.com CNAME [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com)

Comment: The DNS is not supposed to have delegations per record and your case does not work as you can not have a `CNAME` at the same time with any other record (on the same name). Also your question is not very related to programming and hence offtopic here.